# My python IDE and worried about versions

Tags: python

I just got Pycharm Community version and Python version2. something. I just wanna know if  i can have a problem with the versions. Also What is the best way to use Python for?

Comment: Come back when you have a real problem.

Comment: try sublime . what is the issue did you faced in it ?

Comment: The best use for Python is for programming.

Comment: i print something it only shows exit with 0

Answer (score 0):

**PyCharm:** Simplifying things a bit, PyCharm is just a fancy editor. Unless you have it deeply ingrained into your workflow, you can always switch to a different editor, should PyCharm cease to fulfill your needs.

**Python 2** is not the newest version of the language; that would be Python 3.6 as of now (that is, the summer of 2017). So, theoretically, if you start to write lots and lots of code and then later decide, when Python 2 is no longer maintained and third-party libraries drop their support, that all your code should now be compatible with Python 3, you may find yourself in the uncomfortable situation that you suddenly have to port all your code to Python 3, but you lack the ressources to do so. If you recently started programming in Python and have no prior investment, you might consider using Python 3 instead.

Otherwise, simply write modern Python. If you do a serious project, write unittests. Then porting to Python 3 is doable.

**What is the best way to use Python for?** Python is a multi-purpose language used in all kinds of contexts. It is often used in the scientific community. But it's also used a lot for web services, in education, as an embedded scripting language and many of other use cases. What are your interests? Just use Python for that.

Comment: nah! just for fun